# multiplicar el valor en un input y un span

Tags: javascript

tengo un valor en el span y quiero multiplicarlo con el valor que ingreso a travez de un input, esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora

```js
var monto = document.getElementById("1");
    var tasa = document.getElementById('2');   

    function res() {
        var multi = monto.value * tasa.value;
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=multi;
    }
```

```html
<span id="1">5</span>
<input id="2" type="text" onkeyup="res();">
   
<h3 id="resultado">0</h3>
```

Comment: Es mala práctica asignar números como `id` para los elementos. Intenta usar palabras o en todo caso palabras con números.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui te coloco otra forma de resolver el problema, ahora se usa el evento **JAVASCRIPT onkeyup**, se incluye comentarios para la explicacion de cada comando que se esta usando:

1) No se recomienda usar el metodo innerHTML en el caso de `monto.innerHTML` si vas a tomar un valor alfanumerico o numerico por que con este metodo se usa tambien optener el contenido de etiquetas usa `innerText`.

2) Se coloco la funcion `parseFloat()` para obligar a la variable a tomar un valor numero de coma flotante.

```
<span id="1">5</span>
<br>
<input id="2" type="text">    
<br>
<h3 id="resultado">0</h3>

<script type="text/javascript">

     // evento para escuchar cuando pulsan el teclado
     document.getElementById("2").onkeyup = function() { 

             // optener el valor del contenido de la etiqueta sin html
            var monto = document.getElementById("1").innerText;

            // opterner el valor de la etiqueta input
            var tasa = document.getElementById('2').value;

            // se usa el parseFloat() para convertir en numero de coma flotante el valor recibido
            var multi = parseFloat(monto) * parseFloat(tasa);

            // poner valor en etiqueta
            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=multi;
     };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la etiqueta `span` no posee la propiedad `value`, necesitas usar `innerHTML`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
var monto = document.getElementById("1");
    var tasa = document.getElementById('2');   

    function res() {
        var multi = monto.innerHTML * tasa.value;
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=multi;
    }
```

```html
<span id="1">5</span>
<input id="2" type="text" onkeyup="res();">
   
<h3 id="resultado">0</h3>
```